# how to get 4 digits after decimal with floor to the amount?

Tags: python, finance, binance

I want to take a price and divide it by 3 but i can't have the sum of the result bigger then the price i.e

```
price = 0.6096689733333334
four_digits = '{:.{}f}'.format(float(price), 4)
```

returns 0.6097

Is there a way to make it so the result of "four_digits" will be 0.6096 ? (aka the last digit was floored)

Thanks in advance to any helpers!

Comment: Do you want *exactly* 4 decimal digits, or *up to* 4 decimal digits (not showing trailing 0's)?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `math` library

```
import math

price = 0.6096689733333334
four_digits = math.floor(price * 10000)/10000
print(f"{four_digits}")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty ugly and implies that you only have 1 number before the decimal:

```py
price = 0.6096689733333334
float(str(np.round(price, 5))[0:6])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to truncate the result, try this `four_digits = float(str(price)[]:6)`

Convert to string, then cut the 6 digits and then to float again.